# libg2o in ros hydro

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm getting into doing some SLAM development and I am trying to use the libg2o package that I installed using:

**sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-libg2o**.

But, when I run catkin_make I get:

**Could not find module Findlibg2o.cmake or a configuration file for package
libg2o.**

I have tried setting up my CMakeList.txt file several different ways. The above error was obtained using:
find_package(libg2o REQUIRED)

I am running hydro on ubuntu 12.04lts

Thanks

Scott

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102901/libg2o-in-ros-hydro/) by [smishra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4473/smishra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is an old thread but I found a solution on the rgbd-slamv2 code (http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/)

Indeed you need a create a FindG2O.cmake file and put the code below.

```
# Locate the g2o libraries
# A general framework for graph optimization.
#
# This module defines
# G2O_FOUND, if false, do not try to link against g2o
# G2O_LIBRARIES, path to the libg2o
# G2O_INCLUDE_DIR, where to find the g2o header files
#
# Niko Suenderhauf <niko@etit.tu-chemnitz.de>
# Adapted by Felix Endres <endres@informatik.uni-freiburg.de>

IF(UNIX)

  IF(G2O_INCLUDE_DIR AND G2O_LIBRARIES)
    # in cache already
    SET(G2O_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)
  ENDIF(G2O_INCLUDE_DIR AND G2O_LIBRARIES)

  MESSAGE(STATUS "Searching for g2o ...")
  FIND_PATH(G2O_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES core math_groups types
    PATHS /usr/local /usr
    PATH_SUFFIXES include/g2o include)

  IF (G2O_INCLUDE_DIR)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Found g2o headers in: ${G2O_INCLUDE_DIR}")
  ENDIF (G2O_INCLUDE_DIR)

  FIND_LIBRARY(G2O_CORE_LIB             
    NAMES g2o_core 
    PATHS /usr/local /usr 
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
  FIND_LIBRARY(G2O_STUFF_LIB            
    NAMES g2o_stuff 
    PATHS /usr/local /usr 
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
  FIND_LIBRARY(G2O_TYPES_SLAM3D_LIB     
    NAMES g2o_types_slam3d 
    PATHS /usr/local /usr 
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
  FIND_LIBRARY(G2O_SOLVER_CHOLMOD_LIB   
    NAMES g2o_solver_cholmod 
    PATHS /usr/local /usr 
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
  FIND_LIBRARY(G2O_SOLVER_PCG_LIB       
    NAMES g2o_solver_pcg 
    PATHS /usr/local /usr 
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
  FIND_LIBRARY(G2O_SOLVER_CSPARSE_LIB   
    NAMES g2o_solver_csparse 
    PATHS /usr/local /usr 
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
  FIND_LIBRARY(G2O_INCREMENTAL_LIB      
    NAMES g2o_incremental 
    PATHS /usr/local /usr 
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
  FIND_LIBRARY(G2O_CSPARSE_EXTENSION_LIB
    NAMES g2o_csparse_extension
    PATHS /usr/local /usr
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib)

  SET(G2O_LIBRARIES ${G2O_CSPARSE_EXTENSION_LIB}
                    ${G2O_CORE_LIB}           
                    ${G2O_STUFF_LIB}          
                    ${G2O_TYPES_SLAM3D_LIB}   
                    ${G2O_SOLVER_CHOLMOD_LIB} 
                    ${G2O_SOLVER_PCG_LIB}     
                    ${G2O_SOLVER_CSPARSE_LIB} 
                    ${G2O_INCREMENTAL_LIB}                        
                    )
 
  IF(G2O_LIBRARIES AND G2O_INCLUDE_DIR)
    SET(G2O_FOUND "YES")
    IF(NOT G2O_FIND_QUIETLY)
      MESSAGE(STATUS "Found libg2o: ${G2O_LIBRARIES}")
    ENDIF(NOT G2O_FIND_QUIETLY)
  ELSE(G2O_LIBRARIES AND G2O_INCLUDE_DIR)
    IF(NOT G2O_LIBRARIES)
      IF(G2O_FIND_REQUIRED)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find libg2o!")
      ENDIF(G2O_FIND_REQUIRED)
    ENDIF(NOT G2O_LIBRARIES)

    IF(NOT G2O_INCLUDE_DIR)
      IF(G2O_FIND_REQUIRED)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find g2o include directory!")
      ENDIF(G2O_FIND_REQUIRED)
    ENDIF(NOT G2O_INCLUDE_DIR)
  ENDIF(G2O_LIBRARIES AND G2O_INCLUDE_DIR)

ENDIF(UNIX)
```

Also make module and make sure you add it to your CMAKE_MODULE_PATH env variable in cmake. (you can use this line

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-modules/")
```

I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [pmolina](https://answers.ros.org/users/2919/pmolina/) with karma: 108 on 2014-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tanmay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18176/tanmay/) on 2015-05-26**:
Hi,

Could you mention where we are supposed to add the cmake file, and where we need to set CMAKE_MODULE_PATH? Are these in the libg2o package?

Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-02-12**:
@Tanmay in the rgbdslam project the file is at src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/cmake-modules/FindG2O.cmake if that helps. my ros distribution is "Indigo" so you may need to change that to whatever distro you're on.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it's a catkin package you should be using:

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS libg2o ...)

Edit: It's not a catkin package so what you're doing is right. However it appears that libg20 is not installing it's cmake files which are needed for find_package(G2O) to work.

A ticket should be filed with g2o https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/issues

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smishra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4473/smishra/) on 2013-11-20**:
I tried that first and got an error saying that the package libg2o could not be found

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-11-20**:
I do not believe libg2o is a catkin package, it should have its own documentation for how to find and use it.

**Comment by [smishra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4473/smishra/) on 2013-12-03**:
After learning a little bit about CMake and find_package, I found that i needed to use a findG2O.cmake module in order for find_package to work

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2013-12-18**:
the libg2o.pc file is missing in /opt/ros/hydro/lib/pkgconfig/, is that intentional? My belief is that it should be there...

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-18**:
libg2o is *not* a catkin package (see build_type in https://github.com/ros-gbp/libg2o-release/blob/release/hydro/libg2o/2013.07.03-2/package.xml#L30). Therefore it may not provide a pkg-config file if the maintainer has not handcrafted one.

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2013-12-18**:
Don't know if it's a good idea or not, but I just filed a request here: https://github.com/ros-gbp/libg2o-release/issues/2 . A pull request might follow

**Comment by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on 2014-01-09**:
has any one solved this problem?

**Comment by [pnyholm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5202/pnyholm/) on 2014-05-12**:
I second Wilk, I would be very interested to know what the best solution is for this problem

**Comment by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on 2014-09-16**:
It seems that problem has disappeared with time. Anyway up to now I have reinstalled few times ubuntu installation. I am not an expert ros user, I use ros for rgbdslam and it works there- I dont know if in other places too

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem in groovy and hydro.
After comparing fuerte-libg2o with groovy-libg2o, I found out that in /opt/ros/groovy/share/libg2o the folder cmake is missing.
I copied the cmake folder from my fuerte distro and it worked.
You can get the relevant files here:

> [www.dropbox.com/s/l0q4oc7yuk00t92/if_g2o_is_missed.zip](http://www.dropbox.com/s/l0q4oc7yuk00t92/if_g2o_is_missed.zip)

In addition, my compiler had problems finding the cs.h.
Therefore I used the FindSuiteSparse.cmake script (It is included in if_g2o_is_missed.zip).

Inside CMakeLists.txt I handled libg2o like a common catkin-package and added this:

```
find_package(SuiteSparse)
if(CSPARSE_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "CSPARSE_IS_FOUND")
else(CSPARSE_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "CSPARSE_NOTFOUND")
endif(CSPARSE_FOUND)

FIND_PACKAGE(libg2o REQUIRED)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${CSPARSE_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${CHOLMOD_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${libg2o_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

 target_link_libraries(node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${CHOLMOD_LIBRARIES}
   ${CSPARSE_LIBRARIES}
    /usr/lib/libcxsparse.so # not included in findSUITESPARSE cmake macro
   ${libg2o_LIBRARIES}
 )
```

Maybe a better solution would be to create a FindG2O.cmake
Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2